# What does Hinduism say about intelligence?

Tags: karma, birth

I mean  is intelligence something born to a person? Some people are intelligent in studies, some in sports ,some in art?Some people are just intelligent or do they get eventually?

Comment: There's a difference between Talent, Skill, Knowledge and Intelligence.

Comment: It is, like any other quality, based on one's karma.